# Bash terminal not accepting command and has > as prompt

Tags: bash, terminal

This is the 3rd of so time that the terminal froze like this. Instead of exiting again, I thought I'd ask what possible key combination I pressed for this to happen:

[image]

Initially I thought maybe I pressed `Ctrl-s` but `Ctrl-q` is not working. Neither does `Ctrl-c`. I see a blinking cursor but no matter what I type, nothing shows up, except when I press `enter`, that's what more of `>` show up.

In case it makes a difference, I use `tmux`. Haven't encountered this behavior without `tmux` but I don't use the terminal without `tmux` too often.

Comment: Does it always happen after running a specific command?

Comment: @grawity I am not sure. From my perspective, it seems to happen randomly.